# JSNI function not recognized while calling from Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, gwt, smartgwt, jsni

Am having mulitple upload options calling the same servlet for processing.
Am using the parameters to differentiate the calls from GWT, and set the response each time am done with the processing of the file.
The resopnse is being called fine, but the firebug debugger says that its not able to recognize the function

> TypeError: window.parent.uploadCompleteXls is not a function

Below is the servlet code that am using to set the response

```
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
 .
 .

  setResponseXls(response,message)

}

    public void setResponseXls(HttpServletResponse response, String message)   
    {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    PrintWriter out;
    try {
        out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        out.println("window.parent.uploadCompleteXls('" + message + "');");
        out.println("</script>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have written the JSNI method in my GWT class that extends window as below.

```
private static native void initComplete(ProjectRunWindow uploadWindow) /*-{
$wnd.uploadCompleteXls = $entry(function(fileName) {
    this.@com.citi.sevi.web.client.explorer.window.ProjectRunWindow::uploadCompleteXls(Ljava/lang/String;)(fileName);
});
}-*/;

public void uploadCompleteXls(String status) {
    if (!status.equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS")) {

        SC.say(status);
    }
```

The response is not coming back to GWT. 
The Irony is, am exacly using the same syntax in another gwt class that extends window. Its working perfectly fine in the other class !!!.

Comment: Don't forget to escape `message`! If you have a `'` or a `</script>` in the message then at best the code won't work, and at worst you will be subjecting your users to XSS attacks of some kind!

Comment: Are you suggesting some change to the existing code that i have given ?

Comment: Yes, though likely unrelated to the problem you are having. Your 'message' variable in the servlet could potentially subject your users to some form of injected JS attack. Escape the text in 'message' to prevent this.

Comment: Also, consider sharing the class that *does* work - if the same idea works in two places, then the difference is what is causing the change in behavior. What else might be different? Url (domain vs path)? How you open the page? etc.

Comment: Is the use of `window.parent` as opposed to just `window` intended?

Comment: @Bjartr , i tried your suggestion. It didnt help

Comment: What does $entry() do/return? Something is being assigned to uploadCompleteXls, otherwise the error would say it's undefined, not that it's not a function.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen the rest of your client code but I hope you actually called `initComplete(ProjectRunWindow uploadWindow)` to create `$wnd.uploadCompleteXls` in the DOM. If not, that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your jsni method that I see. One is that it is marked as static and just like in java you won't have access to the `this` reference. You can use `console.log(this);` in your static jsni method and you will see that it will print out the $wnd global object. If you are going to invoke a non-static method inside your jsni then the jsni method needs to be non-static. The second is if you are invoking a method in a callback function you still have to add a local var for scope outside of your callback. If you do a console.log inside the callback you will see that it is your inner function and not a reference to the actually gwt class.

```
private native void initComplete(ProjectRunWindow uploadWindow) /*-{
    var self = this;
    $wnd.uploadCompleteXls = $entry(function(fileName) {
        this.@com.citi.sevi.web.client.explorer.window.ProjectRunWindow::uploadCompleteXls(Ljava/lang/String;)(fileName);
    });
}-*/;
```